# supervisord python script : exit status 1; not expected on loop

Tags: python, supervisord

i'm trying to run the following python code using supervisord but it starts restarting the second i execute the supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
Please advise?

```
import urllib2
import time

def goget():
    url = "http://hitch.tv/grabs.php"
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    grabbedpic = data.read()

    with open('/root/python/tmp.txt', 'r') as tmpfile:
        last=tmpfile.read().replace('\n','')

    msgstr = []
    u = 'http://hitch.tv/'

    print last
    if grabbedpic == last:
        print "same pic"
    else:
        msgstr = u + grabbedpic
        //send email with msgstr here 

        with open('tmp.txt', 'w') as tmpfile:
            tmpfile.write(grabbedpic)

    time.sleep(15)

while True:
    goget()
```

here is the log output from supervisord.log

```
> 2014-02-19 22:44:17,993 INFO spawned: 'front' with pid 19859
> 2014-02-19 22:44:19,278 INFO exited: front (exit status 1; not
> expected) 2014-02-19 22:44:20,284 INFO spawned: 'front' with pid 19860
> 2014-02-19 22:44:21,516 INFO exited: front (exit status 1; not
> expected) 2014-02-19 22:44:23,523 INFO spawned: 'front' with pid 19862
> 2014-02-19 22:44:24,805 INFO exited: front (exit status 1; not
> expected) 2014-02-19 22:44:27,814 INFO spawned: 'front' with pid 19863
> 2014-02-19 22:44:29,004 INFO exited: front (exit status 1; not
> expected) 2014-02-19 22:44:30,006 INFO gave up: front entered FATAL
> state, too many start retries too quickly
```

from the supervisord.conf

```
[program:front]
command=python /root/python/front.py
process_name = front
autostart = true
autorestart = true
startsecs = 10
stopwaitsecs = 30
```

Comment: exiting with a non-zero status probably means that the python interpreter is exiting because it caught an exception; normally it'll print the traceback on its stderr, which might be in a log somewhere; perhaps `/var/log/messages`?  If you can't find it anywhere, you should catch the exception yourself and log it where you *can* find it.

Comment: I ran the python script in the terminal for 15 mins straight resulting no errors.  I added the line stdout_logfile=/etc/front.log to the supervisord.conf file and it just outputs the value for 'last' 4 times in the log.

Comment: error messages wouldn't go to stdout; use `stderr_logfile` or `redirect_stderr` with your current `stdout_logfile`.  It's also probalbly not a great idea to put logging in `/etc`; how about `/var/log`?

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: I think logs are in /var/log/supervisor/ by default. app stderr, app stdout, and supervisor logs are all created there.

Answer (score 1):

As `eggonlegs` mentioned in a comment, you can explore further logs by checking your `/var/log/supervisor/` directory. I had the same exact problem, and I found the following file was created:

```
celery_worker-stderr---supervisor-DEjyLf.log
```

(Being the name of my program `[program:front]`).

By examining it I found out that :

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1006, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1030, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/devel.log'
```

So my problem was due to permissions, since I was not specifying a `directory` in my `celery_worker.conf` file. Once specified:

```
directory = /path/to/logs/
```

Everything worked perfectly.

It might not be the same error, but definitely checking these `stderr` or `stdout` logs will help